# Secure transfer of arguments to a program (dash/bash)

Tags: security, arguments, dash

1. Transfer via stdin

```bash
#!/bin/dash
echo 'password' | program -
```

2. Transfer via stdin using an intermediate variable

```bash
var_pass=$(echo 'password')
echo $var_pass | program -
unset var_pass
```

3. Transfer via stdin using an intermediate stream

```bash
echo 'password' | (echo $(cat /dev/fd/4) | program -) 4<&0
```

In terms of possible data interception (compromise), are these options very different? For example, how much the use of an additional variable or thread increases the risk of data theft (from RAM, etc.). Maybe there are other options that are better?

Comment: Related: [Why is printf better than echo?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803) and [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694)

Comment: If you're concerned about data theft from RAM I would suspect you've got bigger issues to consider. Since your examples seem to revolve around providing a password to an application, there might well be better ways of achieving your end aim. For example, with `ssh` it can be better to use public/private certificates and no password at all.